# Let $A$ be a set with $m$ elements and let $B$ be a set with $n$ elements where $m,n\in \omega$ and $m>n$. If $f:A\to B$, then $f$ is not injective

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

So I am still learning how to work with infinite sets, and this particular problem is giving me some issues. Right now, I am trying to pick some $x_1,x_2\in A$ such that $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$ to serve as a counterexample to $f$ being injective. I also know that $A\sim \{1,...m\}$, $B\sim \{1,...n\}$, and $\{1,...,n\}\subset \{1,...m\}$, although I am not sure if either of those two facts help.

Intuitively, the solution makes sense. Lets say we map all $\{1,...,n\}\in A$ to all $\{1,...,n\}\in B$. But then what about the elements in $A\setminus B$, namely $\{n+1,...,m\}$?

I don't know how to go about selecting $x_1,x_2\in A$ such that $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$ without defining $f$ in a specific way, which wouldn't suffice to prove the claim for arbitrary $f$.

Comment: Think about the [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle).

Comment: So if we assume the opposite, i.e. that $f$ is injective, how do we go about showing that the codomain of $f$ is at least as large as $m$, without simply stating it?

Answer (score 1):

Let $| \cdot |$ denote number of elements in $\cdot$

**Proof**. Suppose $f$ injective.

Then $|\{f(A)\}| = |A|$.

But $\{f(A)\} \subset B \implies|\{f(A)\}| \leq |B| = n < m = |A|$, a contradiction.